# Cannot get started in PostGIS Cookbook

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm new to Postgres and am trying to start on chapter 1 in the PostGIS Cookbook. I accessed the terminal and wrote the code exactly how the textbook writes it.

I tried hand-jamming it in, copy and paste, taking out the `$` ... even tried creating a dummy DB (no error code there except when I tried to `$ drops mydb;`

```
postgres=# $ psql -U me -d postgis_cookbook
postgres-# postgis_cookbook=> CREATE TABLE chp01.firenews
postgres-# (
postgres(# x float8,
postgres(# y float8,
postgres(# place varchar(100),
postgres(# size float8,
postgres(# update date,
postgres(# startdate date,
postgres(# enddate date,
postgres(# title varchar(255),
postgres(# url varchar(255),
postgres(# the_geom geometry(POINT, 4326)
postgres(# );
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$"
LINE 1: $ psql -U me -d postgis_cookbook
        ^
```

I also don't know what I am supposed to see after this...

Answer (score 1):

Once you are in the postgres terminal you just need the Postgresql commands, the first part is what you should type in to the linux terminal, the actual postgres commands are the following:

```
postgres-# CREATE TABLE chp01.firenews
postgres-# (
postgres(# x float8,
postgres(# y float8,
postgres(# place varchar(100),
postgres(# size float8,
postgres(# update date,
postgres(# startdate date,
postgres(# enddate date,
postgres(# title varchar(255),
postgres(# url varchar(255),
postgres(# the_geom geometry(POINT, 4326)
postgres(# );
CREATE TABLE
```